# Can we use a Werner state for quantum teleportation?

Tags: density-matrix, schmidt-decomposition, werner-states

Some background:

The quantum teleportation protocol requires first that Alice and Bob *share* an entangled state, say a Bell state $|\psi^{+}\rangle_{AB}$.
There is another state $|\psi\rangle_{A'}$ to which Bob is to receive.
The protocol begins with $|\psi\rangle _{A'} \otimes |\psi^{+}\rangle_{AB}$.

Now, suppose instead of the Bell state I am provided the spatially distributed state as the Werner state is $\rho_{V} = V|\beta(1,1)\rangle\langle\beta(1,1)| + \frac{1-V}{4}$. Clearly, it is a matrix.

My first, and only in fact, approach is to determine the state vector of this Werner state so that I may proceed to understand the effect of replacing a Bell state with a Werner state.

I've been trying to find its state vector but I am unsure how to do so and how to do it efficiently. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's a mixed state with rank greater than 1. It doesn't have a state vector. Instead, you need to learn how to work through the effects of a quantum circuit when applied to a mixed state ($\rho\mapsto U\rho U^\dagger$).

Comment: you can work out explicitly how teleportation works for a generic mixed state, see eg https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/29010/55